# PHP RegEx Negation Word

Tags: php, html, regex, image, regex-lookarounds

My preg_replace pattern regex code here..

```
/<img(.*?)src="(.*?)"/
```

This is my replace code..

```
<img$1src="'.$path.'$2"
```

So i want to negate/exlude a condition..
If img tag have a **rel="customimg"**, dont preg_replace so skip it..

Example: Skip This Line

```
<img rel="customimg" src="http..">
```

What might add to this regex pattern?

I searched another post, but I couldn't exactly..

Comment: Please don't try to parse HTML using regex. Use [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) or another HTML parser. It may seem to work at first but it will bite you in the ass later.

Comment: Agree with @PeeHaa. Your code would be more clear and extensible if you used `DOMDocument` to get all `<img>` and tested if they contained `rel="customimg"`.

Comment: For a list of real solutions see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-with-php

Comment: I thought and tried its anyway.. I need just a right regex syntax..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `src` argument may use single or double quotes, I suggest you to use

```
preg_replace(
  "/(<img\b(?!.*\brel=[\"']customimg[\"']).*?\bsrc=)([\"']).*?\2/i",
  "$1$2" . $path . "$2",
  $string);
```

#### Edit:

To add url prefix instead of full url replacement, use

```
preg_replace(
  "/(<img\b(?!.*\brel=[\"']customimg[\"']).*?\bsrc=)([\"'])(.*?)\2/i",
  "$1$2" . $path . "$3$2",
  $string);
```

Comment: @m.buettner - Friend, can you help me, please? Why this one is not working >> http://ideone.com/72hCSW but it is okay here >> http://gskinner.com/RegExr/?32ihj ? Please feel free edit my answer and post comment to notify OP. Thank you.

Comment: http://regexr.com?32ii2 >> almost done.. remain a little issue.. you will see replaced path is [src="PATH"].. it must be [src="PATH/images/logo.jpg"].. So not new path.. My $path variable + old image path.. I wont parse img tags that have customimg, if no have, it will be parsed (src="baseurl+imageurl")..

Comment: @Bora - My http://gskinner.com/RegExr/?32ihj as published in my previous comment is wokring fine, the problem I have is with PHP code. Anyway... You are asking now to not replacing url link, but add some prefix to it, right? Then you have to change end of my pattern from `.*?\2` to `(.*?)\2` and as replacement you need to use `"$1$2" . $path . "$3$2"` >> http://regexr.com?32ii5

Answer (score 1):

Add a negative lookahead:

```
/<img(?![^>]*\srel="customimg")(.*?)src="(.*?)"/
```

Comment: Please post your exact code then, because I don't see why the above shouldn't work, unless you have ``>``s within your ``img`` tag.

Comment: $html = "WEBSITE ALL HTML CODE"

$exp = array( '/<img(.*?)src=(?:")(http|https)\:\/\/([^"]+?)(?:")/i', '/<img(.*?)src=(?:")([^"]+?)#(?:")/i', **'/<img(.*?)src="(.*?)"/'**, '/<img(.*?)src=(?:\@)([^"]+?)(?:\@)/i' );

$sub = array( '<img$1src=@$2://$3@', '<img$1src=@$2@', **'<img$1src="'.$path.'$2"'**, '<img$1src="$2"' );

preg_replace( $exp, $sub, $html );

Comment: I can confirm that it works. If you have spaces before the closing `>` you can add `\s*` to the regex: `<img(?![^>]*\srel="customimg")(.*?)src="(.*?)"\s*>`

Answer (score 1):

Because I only see regex "solutions" coming in. Here is the answer using DOMDocument:

```
<?php
$path = 'the/path';

$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML('<img rel="customimg" src="/image.jpgm"><img src="/image.jpg">');
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$imageNodes = $xpath->query('//img[not(@rel="customimg")]');

foreach ($imageNodes as $node) {
    $node->setAttribute('src', $path . $node->getAttribute('src'));
}
```

Demo: http://codepad.viper-7.com/uID5wz

Answer (score 0):

It would seem like it'd be easier/more expressive to do

```
if(strpos($haystackString, '"customimg"') === false) // The === is important
{
 // your preg_replace here
}
```

Edit: Thanks for pointing out missing param guys

Comment: I tried strpos before..
But i parse all html preg_replace with arrays..
I cant use this function..

Comment: @Martin: `strpos('some string')` is missing an arg.

Comment: Apologies for that guys, corrected. Sorry it didn't suit your requirement Bora